# Getting an error message in pygame

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

```
     import pygame
     import random
     from os import path

     img_dir = path.join(path.dirname(__file__), 'img')
     snd_dir = path.join(path.dirname(__file__), 'sound')


     WIDTH = 800
     HEIGHT = 600
     FPS = 50

     WHITE=(255, 255, 255)
     BLACK=(0, 0, 0)
     RED=(255, 0, 0)
     GREEN=(0, 255, 0)
     BLUE=(0, 0, 255)
     YELLOW=(255, 255, 0)

     pygame.init()
     pygame.mixer.init()

     screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
     pygame.display.set_caption("My Game")
     clock = pygame.time.Clock()

     font_name = pygame.font.match_font('arial')

     end = True
     def start_screen():
         draw_text(screen, "SPACE SHOOTING", 70, WIDTH/2, HEIGHT/4)
         draw_text(screen, "INSTRUCTIONS", 25, WIDTH/2, HEIGHT/2)
         draw_text(screen, "Press Left arrow key to move left", 20, WIDTH/2, HEIGHT*2/3.5)
     draw_text(screen, "Press Right arrow key to move right", 20, WIDTH/2, HEIGHT*2/3.3)
draw_text(screen, "Spacebar to shoot", 20, WIDTH/2, HEIGHT*2/3.1)
draw_text(screen, "Press a key to begin", 20, WIDTH/2, HEIGHT*3/4)
pygame.display.flip()
wait = True
while wait:
    clock.tick(FPS)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                wait = False




     def draw_text(surf, text, size, x, y):
          font = pygame.font.Font(font_name, size)
          text_surface = font.render(text, True, WHITE)
          text_rect = text_surface.get_rect()
          text_rect.midtop = (x, y)
          surf.blit(text_surface, text_rect)



   class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
       def __init__(self):
          pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
          self.image = pygame.transform.scale(player_img, (50, 38))
          self.image.set_colorkey(BLACK)
          self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
          self.radius = 20
          self.rect.centerx = WIDTH/2
          self.rect.bottom = HEIGHT - 10
          self.speedx = 0

     def update(self):
         self.speedx = 0
         keystate = pygame.key.get_pressed()
          if keystate[pygame.K_LEFT]:
             self.speedx = -5
          if keystate[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
             self.speedx = 5
             self.rect.x += self.speedx
          if self.rect.right > WIDTH:
             self.rect.right = WIDTH
          if self.rect.left < 0:
             self.rect.left = 0

def shoot(self):
    bullet = Bullets(self.rect.centerx, self.rect.top)
    all_sprites.add(bullet)
    bullets.add(bullet)

class Aliens(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
  def __init__(self):
    pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
    self.image = aliens_img
    self.image.set_colorkey(BLACK)
    self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
    self.radius = int(self.rect.width*.85/2)
    self.rect.x = random.randrange(WIDTH - self.rect.width)
    self.rect.y = random.randrange(-100, -40)
    self.speedy = random.randrange(1, 8)

def update(self):
    self.rect.y += self.speedy
    if self.rect.top > HEIGHT + 10 or self.rect.left < -25 or       self.rect.right > WIDTH + 20:
        self.rect.x = random.randrange(WIDTH - self.rect.width)
        self.rect.y = random.randrange(-100, -40)
        self.speedy = random.randrange(1, 8)

class SuperAliens(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
  def __init__(self):
    pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
    self.image = superaliens_img
    self.image.set_colorkey(BLACK)
    self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
    self.radius = int(self.rect.width*.85/2)
    self.rect.x = random.randrange(WIDTH - self.rect.width)
    self.rect.y = random.randrange(-100, -40)
    self.speedy = random.randrange(1, 8)
    self.speedx = random.randrange(-3, 3)

def update(self):
    self.rect.x += self.speedx
    self.rect.y += self.speedy
    if self.rect.top > HEIGHT + 10 or self.rect.left < -25 or self.rect.right > WIDTH + 20:
        self.rect.x = random.randrange(WIDTH - self.rect.width)
        self.rect.y = random.randrange(-100, -40)
        self.speedy = random.randrange(1, 8)

def shoot1(self):
    sbullet = SBullets(self.rect.centerx, self.rect.bottom)
    all_sprites.add(sbullet)
    bullets.add(sbullet)



class SBullets(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
  def __init__(self, x, y):
    pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
    self.image = sbullet_img
    self.image.set_colorkey(BLACK)
    self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
    self.rect.bottom = y
    self.rect.centerx = x
    self.speedy = +10

def update(self):
    self.rect.y += self.speedy
    if self.rect.top < 0:
        self.kill()

class Bullets(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
  def __init__(self, x, y):
    pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
    self.image = bullet_img
    self.image.set_colorkey(BLACK)
    self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
    self.rect.bottom = y
    self.rect.centerx = x
    self.speedy = -10

def update(self):
    self.rect.y += self.speedy
    if self.rect.bottom < 0:
        self.kill()

 class Explode(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
  def __init__(self, center, size):
    pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
    self.size = size
    self.image = explode[self.size][0]
    self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
    self.rect.center = center
    self.frame = 0
    self.last_update = pygame.time.get_ticks()
    self.frame_rate = 2

def update(self):
    now = pygame.time.get_ticks()
    if now - self.last_update > self.frame_rate:
        self.last_update = now
        self.frame += 1
        if self.frame == len(explode[self.size]):
            self.kill()
        else:
            center = self.rect.center
            self.image = explode[self.size][self.frame]
            self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
            self.rect.center = center





 background = pygame.image.load(path.join(img_dir, "back.png")).convert()
  background_rect = background.get_rect()
  player_img = pygame.image.load(path.join(img_dir, "playerShip2_blue.png")).convert()
  superaliens_img = pygame.image.load(path.join(img_dir, "enemyBlack4.png")).convert()
  aliens_img = pygame.image.load(path.join(img_dir, "enemyBlack1.png")).convert()
  bullet_img = pygame.image.load(path.join(img_dir, "laserRed16.png")).convert()
  sbullet_img = pygame.image.load(path.join(img_dir, "laserRed11.png")).convert()
  explode = {}
  explode['super']=[]
  explode['small']=[]
 for i in range(9):
   filename = 'regularExplosion02.png'.format(1)
    img = pygame.image.load(path.join(img_dir, filename)).convert()
img.set_colorkey(BLACK)
img_super = pygame.transform.scale(img, (75, 75))
explode ['super'].append(img_super)
img_small = pygame.transform.scale(img, (32, 32))
explode ['small'].append(img_small)


#pygame.mixer.music.load(path.join(snd_dir, 'Orbital.mp3'))
#pygame.mixer.music.set_volume(0.4)


#pygame.mixer.music.play(loops=-1)
end_game = True
running = True
while running:
 if end_game:
    start_screen()
    end_game = False
    all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
    aliens = pygame.sprite.Group()
    superaliens = pygame.sprite.Group()
    bullets = pygame.sprite.Group()
    sbullets = pygame.sprite.Group()
    player = Player()
    all_sprites.add(player)
    for i in range(5):
        m = Aliens()
        all_sprites.add(m)
        aliens.add(m)

    for j in range(1):
        n = SuperAliens()
        all_sprites.add(n)
        superaliens.add(n)

    score = 0
clock.tick(FPS)
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        running = False
    elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
            player.shoot()

all_sprites.update()

hits = pygame.sprite.groupcollide(aliens, bullets, True, True)
for hit in hits:
    score += 1
    m = Aliens()
    expl = Explode(hit.rect.center, 'small')
    all_sprites.add(expl)
    all_sprites.add(m)
    aliens.add(m)

hits = pygame.sprite.groupcollide(superaliens, bullets, True, True)
for hitt in hits:
    score += 5
    n = SuperAliens()
    expl1 = Explode(hitt.rect.center, 'super')
    all_sprites.add(expl1)
    all_sprites.add(n)
    superaliens.add(n)

hits = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(player, aliens, True)
for hit in hits:
    expl = Explode(hit.rect.center, 'small')
    all_sprites.add(expl)
    if hits:
        end_game = True
hits = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(player, superaliens, True)
for hitt in hits:
    expl1 = Explode(hitt.rect.center, 'super')
    all_sprites.add(expl1)
    if hits:
        end_game = True

screen.fill(BLACK)
screen.blit(background, background_rect)
all_sprites.draw(screen)
draw_text(screen,"SCORE" +str(score), 22, WIDTH/2, 10)
#after drwing everything flip the display
pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
```

Sorry for the bad formatting but couldn't upload it with the proper formatting. Its my first pygame, so im not good in it. The program is working good, but every time when i close the window, its is showing me this error. 
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/Users/Documents/game.py", line 221, in 
    start_screen()
    File "/Users/Documents/game.py", line 41, in start_screen
    for event in pygame.event.get():
    pygame.error: video system not initialized

I was also trying to make the super aliens shoot randomly towards the player, and that thing is not working as well.A little help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

After the line:

```
pygame.quit()
```

put:

```
exit()
```

Basically, `pygame.quit()` tells pygame that you are done with it. After you call it in your event loop, pygame no longer can draw things to the screen, but you still try to make it do so later in your program. Calling `exit()` makes python exit so that pygame is not told to draw anything.